# Deploy Angular app with Gulp on Heroku: app crashed

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku, gulp

I have a Node.js + Angular web app that is using Gulp. It works perfectly in my local machine when I run the command "gulp serve".

I am trying to deploy it in Heroku following some resources I found online, so I have done the following.

I have created a new file called **web.js** in the root directory with this content:

```
var gzippo = require('gzippo');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/build"));
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000);
```

I have created a new file called **Procfile** in the root directory with this content:

```
web: node web.js
```

This is the package.json file. Please note that I have added `gulp serve` as start script and `bower install` as postinstall because it is the way it works locally.

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.13.3",
    "bower": "1.6.5",
    "gzippo": "^0.2.0",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "gulp test",
    "start": "gulp serve",
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install --config.interactive=false && gulp build"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~2.3.1",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~1.6.0",
    "del": "~1.2.0",
    "lodash": "~3.9.3",
    "gulp-csso": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "~2.0.2",
    "gulp-flatten": "~0.0.4",
    "gulp-jshint": "~1.11.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~0.10.0",
    "gulp-size": "~1.2.1",
    "gulp-uglify": "~1.2.0",
    "gulp-useref": "~1.2.0",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.5",
    "gulp-ng-annotate": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-replace": "~0.5.3",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
    "gulp-rev": "~5.0.0",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
    "gulp-minify-html": "~1.0.3",
    "gulp-inject": "~1.3.1",
    "gulp-protractor": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.5.2",
    "gulp-sass": "~2.0.1",
    "gulp-angular-filesort": "~1.1.1",
    "main-bower-files": "~2.8.0",
    "merge-stream": "~0.1.7",
    "jshint-stylish": "~2.0.0",
    "wiredep": "~2.2.2",
    "karma": "~0.12.36",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.5",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-angular-filesort": "~0.1.0",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.1.2",
    "concat-stream": "~1.5.0",
    "require-dir": "~0.3.0",
    "browser-sync": "~2.7.12",
    "browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.2",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "~0.0.5",
    "chalk": "~1.0.0",
    "uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
    "wrench": "~1.5.8"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  }
}
```

I have run these commands before the push:

```
heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=production
```

and I have set the buildpack to: `https://github.com/appstack/heroku-buildpack-nodejs-gulp.git`

The app is deploying without errors, including all the bower install process. The logs only shows "app crashed". Any ideas?

Comment: hey did you find a solution for that i am facing the same problem since three weeks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into the same error above, app was crashing on heroku (running fine in dev) but error logs on heroku were not revealing any clues. I figured maybe I could get in the heroku console and look around. I did and even the console crashed, but this time it told me why. It was some obscure variable I forgot to delete during a troubleshooting session hours earlier. I am not saying you will run into the same problem, but I found more info when I tried to go through the console. Hope this helps.

Comment: Do you mean running heroku logs --tail while I open the website on my browser?